# How to globally createConnection() with TypeORM in unit tests?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, tdd, typeorm

I have a [node.js application inside TypeORM's `createConnection()` body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55400355/2404470):

```
// index.ts
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";
createConnection().then(async connection => {
    // express app code here
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Now, I wanted to write unit test cases using [`jest`](https://jestjs.io/) and I wanted the connection to be available across the tests

```
// abc.test.ts
createConnection().then(async connection => {

    describe('ABC controller tests', () => {
        it('should test abc function1', async () => {
            // test body does here                
        });       
    });
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

I have a few concerns:

- This is my first time working with TypeORM, so I don't have any hands-on experience on it
- It doesn't even work & throws `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`
- It looks like a very ugly approach
- I wanted the connection making code at only one place, not in every test file but there is no **entry point**  for tests like the app has `index.ts`

> How to globally createConnection() with TypeORM in unit tests?

Comment: Yesterday I wrote an answer about this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62200568/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-writing-test-wi)

Comment: @Teneff error is only part of the problem - I wanted to know how to globally create the connection! Btw, thanks for the help! The error is gone now!

Answer (score 3):

You should use `beforeEach` and `afterEach` to set up your state/context/world. Something like:

```
describe('ABC controller tests', () => {
    let connection: Connection

    beforeEach(async () => {
      connection = await createConnection()
    })

    it('should test abc function1', async () => {
        connection.doSomething()
    })

    afterEach(async () => {
        await connection.close()
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create

**`jest.setup.js`** [(setupFilesAfterEnv)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array)

```js
// Promise<Connection>
global.connection = createConnection()
```

and then you can await the Promise to be resolved in your tests

**`abc.test.ts`**

```js
describe('abc', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await global.connection
  });

  it('should be connected', () => {
    // not sure if that property really exists
    expect(global.connection).toHaveProperty('isConnected', true)
  })
})
```